# Show full disguise in replays?

Tags: pc, team-fortress-2

If I have a replay in the new replay editor and I'm a Spy, how can I switch it so I show up as the actual class I'm disguised as? Even if I change to the enemy team from their view, I still show up as a Spy wearing a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is not currently a way to do this.  This is because when you watch replays you are on team spectator, so you can see all spies with their masks on.